# Find from mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to fine this time and this name by this code

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("8:00:00"));
$t= $collection->find('$and' => array( array('date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)),array('name' =>$name)));
```

but i get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in {C:\xampp\htdocs\test\result.php on line 305}
```

so why i get this?

Comment: $score1=array('date'=>array('$gt' => $start1, '$lte' => $end1),'name'=>$_POST['name']);

Answer (score 0):

The `find` function accepts an array, but you gave something that's not of any variable type (`'$and' => array()`). I'm not sure how to correct your code because it's unclear to me what you are looking for, but from a syntax point of view, removing the `'$and' =>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t= $collection->find(['$and' => array('date' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end),array('name' =>$name))]);
```